# Where to remove observer for NSNotificationCenter in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I dont want to add observer in viewDidAppear and remove in viewDidDisappear.Will not serve my case.

I have tried doing it in dealloc.

My root VC is in navController.Then a second VC is pushed in navController, where I addObserver for notifications to be sent from rootVC.The problem is when I pop the secondVC its dealloc is not called immediately or may be somtimes not called alltogether.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(newMessagesNotification:) name:_newMessageNotificationListenerName object:nil];
}

- (void)newMessagesNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
//some implementation
}
```

Comment: Why not `viewDidDisappear`?  If `dealloc` isn't being called then something is holding a reference to the view controller.

Comment: Not in viewDidDisappear because I bring another VC modally in secondVC.One can argue to put if conditons in viewDidDisappear.But I am looking for a concrete apple suggested way to remove observer in a VC

Comment: Dealloc then. You need to work out what is holding the reference

Comment: How would you go about if my secondVC in presented modally and I dismiss it( I am 100% sure dealloc is not called when dismissing modally).What will you do then.

Comment: If dealloc isn't called then something is still holding a strong reference.

Comment: The apple suggested way is to register in viewDidLoad/When the observation is needed and deregistering on dealloc. If dealloc isn't called when your modal disappears you probably have a reference cycle or something is holding a strong reference to your modal. Solve that problem first, and then put in dealloc.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to remove in the ViewDidDisapear than i think you should remove it right after you called the navigationCotnroller pop methode. But I think we can't tell you the exact moment when you should remove because we don't know when you want to remove it and why it isn't good in the ViewWillDisapier or in the ViewDidDisapier.

Comment: I am calling popToRootVc from other controllers.Hence, i was more interested in dealloc method.I want to call it as soon as i remove secondVC from navigation stack.Please read my comments as to why not in ViewWillDisappear.